# Dividing a deck among four people, multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

> A deck of cards has 52 cards. We randomly divide the cards among 4 players, each getting 13 cards. What is the total number of ways the cards can be divided among the 4 players, assuming we don't make a distinction among the players?

We can use binomial or multinomial coefficients:

$${52 \choose 13 \space13 \space13 \space 13} = {52 \choose 13} {39 \choose 13} { 26 \choose 13} {13 \choose 13}$$

However, apparently we have to divide by $4!$ "because the order of the players doesn't matter". Intuitively, I'm having trouble grasping why we have to divide it by $4!$ (even though I know the reason). I don't grok it.

When I use multinomial coefficients, I use permutations of letters to provide intuition, e.g.:

${8 \choose 2 \space 2 \space 2 \space 2}$ is the number of unique letter sequences of $AABBCCDD$. By dividing by $4!$, what kind of different solutions are we "merging"? Things like $AABBCCDD$ and $BBCCDDAA$ would be considered as one, perhaps? Can anyone help provide me with intuition?

Comment: Your multinomial coefficient should read $$\binom{52}{13, 13, 13, 13}$$